# when i open my app , how to avoid BottomBar automatically selected AboutusTab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

when i open my application,default selected Home_Tab is opened,working fine....but in this Home_Tab,Bottombar also there ,i dont want default selection tab of About Us??
if i want click AboutUs_Tab that time it will open??? 
but in this above image when i open Home_Tab ,automatically selected AboutUs_Tab but not opened it ,will try to click that aboutUs_Tab not working???
When i click ContactUS_Tab and return to AboutUs_Tab ,that time AboutUS_Tab opened??how to avoid this issue??
[image]

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Context context;
//This is our tablayout
private TabLayout tabLayout;
BottomBar bottombar;

//This is our viewPager
private ViewPager viewPager;
public ViewPagerAdapter FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    bottombar = BottomBar.attach(MainActivity.this, savedInstanceState);
    bottombar.noNavBarGoodness();
    bottombar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_bar_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.about_us:
                    About_Us about_us = new About_Us();
                    About_Fragment about_fragment = new About_Fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Home_BottomBar_Fragment, about_fragment).commit();

                    break;
                case R.id.contact_us:
                    ContactUs_Activity contactUs_activity = new ContactUs_Activity();
                    Contact_us_Fragment contact_us_fragment = new Contact_us_Fragment();
                    FragmentManager fm2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft2 = fm2.beginTransaction();
                    ft2.replace(R.id.Home_BottomBar_Fragment, contact_us_fragment).commit();
                    //squareFragment.updateColor(Color.parseColor(colors[1]));
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"selected contact_us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.donate_us:
                    Donate_us_Fragment donate_us_fragment = new Donate_us_Fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Home_BottomBar_Fragment, donate_us_fragment).commit();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"selected donate_us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    });


    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home").setIcon(R.drawable.home_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("News").setIcon(R.drawable.news_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Videos").setIcon(R.drawable.video_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("PodCasts").setIcon(R.drawable.podcast_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("More").setIcon(R.drawable.more_selector));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    //tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                bottombar.show();
                //bottombar.getCurrentTabPosition();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                bottombar.hide();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                bottombar.hide();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                bottombar.hide();
            }else if (tab.getPosition() == 4){
                bottombar.hide();
            }
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabUnselected(tab);

            //tab.getIcon().setAlpha(127);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outstate);

    // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
    // lose the current tab on orientation change.
    bottombar.onSaveInstanceState(outstate);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the default selected tab in bottom bar with:

```
bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(1);
```

Use this after initializing the bottom bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one dummy invisible item for make your thinks work. For that create one more item :

```
<item android:id="@+id/none"
android:title=""/>
```

where you create your items. And then in your code change to this :

```
bottombar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_bar_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.none:
                    break;
                case R.id.about_us:
                    About_Us about_us = new About_Us();
                    About_Fragment about_fragment = new About_Fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Home_BottomBar_Fragment, about_fragment).commit();

                    break;
                case R.id.contact_us:
                    ContactUs_Activity contactUs_activity = new ContactUs_Activity();
                    Contact_us_Fragment contact_us_fragment = new Contact_us_Fragment();
                    FragmentManager fm2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft2 = fm2.beginTransaction();
                    ft2.replace(R.id.Home_BottomBar_Fragment, contact_us_fragment).commit();
                    //squareFragment.updateColor(Color.parseColor(colors[1]));
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"selected contact_us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.donate_us:
                    Donate_us_Fragment donate_us_fragment = new Donate_us_Fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Home_BottomBar_Fragment, donate_us_fragment).commit();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"selected donate_us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i dont want select any tab in bottombar...if i want click any tab in bottom that time it will open then how??

Comment: You must select some tab from bottombar. For your case create a dummy(not used) tab. I edit my post, you can try it :)

Comment: DUMMY item is created , and when i open my app , it was looking not good and some space is created in front of AboutUs tab....without bottombar method or code, any other alternate is there creating of tabs in bottom

Comment: Try this: 
bottombar.getItem(0).setVisible(false);